# LuaLaTeX tex.print function fails, while the text written to file and pasted to tex works without errors

Tags: luatex, lua

I'm relatively new to both LaTeX and Lua, so you can imagine I'm quite stumped by this error. Situation is as follows:

- I am working on [this repository at the given "scripts" branch](https://github.com/lHeidbreder/neon-rules/tree/scripts).
- I am trying to fill a template with information from a CSV file.
- I am using addon-ai/ai-rules.tex for testing because it only contains a single entry, i.e.  template = scripts/templates/race.tpl and CSV file = addon-ai/ai-races.csv.
- The Lua import script is scripts/lua/csv-importer.lua
- I am compiling using `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ai-rules".tex` under Windows (leaving all options in case there might be a strange interaction)

When I try to compile my PDF with while line 99 in said script `tex.sprint(filledtemplate)` is not commented, compilation fails with rather obscure errors, the first one I found being `! Misplaced \noalign.`.

When I run the same command while line 99 is commented and line 100 `writetofile(filledtemplate)` is uncommented, then copy and paste the content of the file it produced into my document and compile using that rather than the script, my PDF compiles without any errors and looks the way I want it to.

I have tried using both `tex.print` as well as `tex.sprint`, both to the same effect.

I have checked for rogue symbols that I know or expect to have special meaning in LaTeX, i.e. `\`, `%`, `&` and `@`, and have not found anything out of the ordinary.

I have not found any similar issues online, so I assume this to be a user error, but at this point I really don't know where to look.

Comment: don't use external links make a small self contained example here. Your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if that link breaks or you change the code there

Comment: Add a regular `print(whatever)` right before `tex.sprint(whatever)` so that you can see what exactly is making `tex.sprint` fail.